# React-Native - SyntaxError: Identifier has already been declared

Tags: javascript, react-native

Pleace help!.. I want to create a Bottom Sheet Dialog where when loading the page, the dialog will appear at the bottom and then it can be stretched if it is pulled up and will disappear if it is slide down. However, I have this error:

`**"SytaxError: Identifier 'BottomSheetProps' has already been declared."**`

I have tried to rename the **BottomSheetProps** variable but still get error, please help

```
import { Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import { Gesture, GestureDetector } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {Extrapolate,interpolate,useAnimatedStyle,useSharedValue,withSpring,withTiming,} from 'react-native-reanimated';

const { height: SCREEN_HEIGHT } = Dimensions.get('window');
const MAX_TRANSLATE_Y = -SCREEN_HEIGHT + 50;

type BottomSheetProps = {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
};

export type BottomSheetRefProps = {
  scrollTo: (destination: number) => void;
  isActive: () => boolean;
};

const BottomSheet = React.forwardRef<BottomSheetRefProps, BottomSheetProps>(
  ({ children }, ref) => {
    const translateY = useSharedValue(0);
    const active = useSharedValue(false);

    const scrollTo = useCallback((destination: number) => {
      'worklet';
      active.value = destination !== 0;
      translateY.value = withSpring(destination, { damping: 50 });
    }, []);

    const isActive = useCallback(() => {
      return active.value;
    }, []);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ scrollTo, isActive }), [
      scrollTo,
      isActive,
    ]);

    const context = useSharedValue({ y: 0 });
    const gesture = Gesture.Pan()
      .onStart(() => {
        context.value = { y: translateY.value };
      })
      .onUpdate((event) => {
        translateY.value = event.translationY + context.value.y;
        translateY.value = Math.max(translateY.value, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
      })
      .onEnd(() => {
        if (translateY.value > -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 3) {
          scrollTo(0);
        } else if (translateY.value < -SCREEN_HEIGHT / 1.5) {
          scrollTo(MAX_TRANSLATE_Y);
        }
      });

    const rBottomSheetStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
      const borderRadius = interpolate(
        translateY.value,
        [MAX_TRANSLATE_Y + 50, MAX_TRANSLATE_Y],
        [25, 5],
        Extrapolate.CLAMP
      );

      return {
        borderRadius,
        transform: [{ translateY: translateY.value }],
      };
    });

    return (
      <GestureDetector gesture={gesture}>
        <Animated.View style={[styles.bottomSheetContainer, rBottomSheetStyle]}>
          <View style={styles.line} />
          {children}
        </Animated.View>
      </GestureDetector>
    );
  }
);

export default BottomSheet;
```

Comment: "However, I have this error" - on which line?